# How to change config variables during the session only

Tags: configuration, store, config, magento

I need to get a config variable and change it for the session only
I have this Observer, and I've managed to change the variable via setNode. If in the next line I verify its value by using getNode(), value has changed correctly.
However later in other views I check for Mage::getStoreConfig('oi_options/messages/active') and it seems to have 0 again. As you can see I put cleanCache() and reinit(). I have tried with both of them and each of them isolately. 
In addition, I use a few ifconfig statements in xml layouts to check for this variable as well in order to determine whether to display a few blocks and it does not work either.
Any suggestions?

```
class Oi_Vendedor_Model_Observer {

const RETAILER = 3;

public function checkVendedor(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $customerGroup = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();

    if(($customerGroup == self::RETAILER) && (Mage::getStoreConfig('oi_options/messages/active') == 0))
    {
        Mage::getConfig()->setNode('default/oi_options/messages/active',1);
        Mage::getConfig()->cleanCache();
        Mage::getConfig()->reinit();
    } 
    return $this;
}
```

}

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems like you are trying to do some sort of state persistence. This isn't the way to do this in the Magento framework. Can you comment/edit with what you'd like to accomplish?

Comment: Are you sure your observer is invoked before layout is loaded?

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a simple way to do that.

Let's say I have the value `'my/config/key'` set to `1` in the database.

After some event, I set the value to `0` this way:

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->setConfig('my/config/key', 0);
```

Then accessing this value will return `0` until the end of the script execution:

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('my/config/key'); //return 0
```

However the value in the database is still `1`.

I didn't use the solution with the session because I needed it to impact the ifconfig in the XML layouts.

Answer (score 0):

@Ben This is exactly what I wanted to accomplish. What I finally did in order to keep this pseudo-state persistence was to load a personal session variable with the value I needed to check. I thought there was a way to keep backend config variables accessible from the session and eventually change their value on the fly, like objects naturally work.
I mean, keep admin info in the session as well. I could not find a way to do this so I had to go for the personal session variable option.
Btw, it works like charm now. Thanks for your comments guys.